# ui-router state empty {"name":"","url":"^","views":null,"abstract":true}

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following configuration for my route:

```
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
        url: '/',
        template: '<home>'
    })

.state('manage', {
    url: 'manage',
    abstract: true,
    template:'<div ui-view></div>'
})

.state('manage.map', {
    parent: 'manage',
    url: '/map',
    template: '<dummy>'
})
```

in my index. html, I have a ui-view :

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

The problem i am having is that when i try to access the child state, it is sometimes empty `$state.current` looks like this `{"name":"","url":"^","views":null,"abstract":true}`

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: yes in this part .state('manage', {
    url: 'manage',
    abstract: true,
    template:'<div ui-view></div>'
}) a '/' was missing